# How to call SOAP webserivce and how to set proxy setting?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy

I want to call webservice(SOAP) through proxy.
Suppose, proxy username:xyz and password :xyz

**Webservice url**: https://xyz.com/pqr

**service name** : uploadData

I have used

```
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "some host");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "some port");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "username");
    System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "password"); // I have also tried base64 password.
```

but It throws Authentication required exception.

Basically I need to call this webservice with some parameter and get response from it.

Thank You..

Comment: what library are you using or just plain httpconnection?

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy I calling webservice using QName,Service, SOAPMessage etc.

Comment: Consider the use of a pure HTTP client to send the created SOAP message or another suite with proxy support and the hability to set the authentication per connection basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use the Authenticator like

```
final PasswordAuthentication AUTHENTICATOR = new PasswordAuthentication(proxyUser, proxyPassword.toCharArray());
                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
                    {
                        if( ObjectUtil.equals(getRequestorType(), Authenticator.RequestorType.PROXY) ) {
                            return AUTHENTICATOR;
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Caution with the Authenticator Object from JVM, java.net.Authenticator cannot be set on a per-connection basis, so if you are using an Application Server with another apps using their own Authenticators the "Authenticator.setDefault()" method of your app will rewrite the previously defined Authenticator and the other apps will fail. There are some opened bugs about this behaviour  http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4941958